# Pretty print HashSet in Java

Tags: java, jackson, hashset

I could find questions closer to this one, but not exactly what i was looking for. The problem is possibly pretty simple for many experts: I have a `Hashset` containing my customized bean as its content:

```
Set<TableColumnBean> mySet = new HashSet<TableColumnBean>();
//loop and add values to Hashset
for(String str : tableColumnBeanMap.keySet()){
    mySet.add(new TableColumnBean(tableColumnBeanMap.get(str).getTable, `tableColumnBeanMap.get(str).getColumn))`
}
```

Here tableColumnBeanMap is a Map which contains list of beans of the type `TableColumnBean`. `TableColumnBean` is a simple bean which has two properties table and column. At the end of the loop, i want to pretty print the contents of set, which will be useful to keep as a debug log option. I could think of looping over the set using java for loop and prinitng contents. But at other places i have used `Jackson` library like:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myMap)
```

which works wonderfully on maps. Do we have something similar which works on Sets as well? (Something one liner like Jackson's pretty print would be nice - as it produces very nice to read output format and also doesn't clutter your code either).

Comment: why not convert your set to map then use the objectmapper?

Comment: Hi Salman, i don't have a key in this case, just a bean to add. I thought Map would be more appropriate when you need key-value pair. A list would have done the job for me, but i wanted unique elements only, that's why set

Comment: What is the problem of using `new ObjectMapper().writeWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mySet)`?

Comment: Hi Wilson, this is embarrasing, but i admit my silly mistake. you're right - prettyprint is working in this case. I had misread another error, thrown by same line of code, jumped the gun and made up my mind that prettyprint is not working for set, while it does. Thank you for pointing it out ! And my apologies for such a silly mistake

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
import java.util.*;

Arrays.toString(mySet.toArray())
```

creates a string from the elements of `mySet`.